# Can´t seem to fix null situation with object in C# (Object reference not set to an instance of an object.)

Tags: c#, object, datatable, null, instance

My DataTable object seems to be null, but I dont understand why. I am trying to add three variables to it, but it still says it is null. Here is my code :

```
    DataTable dt;

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    private void InitDataTable()
    {

        if (!File.Exists("gjesteInfo.xml"))
        {
            dt = new DataTable("Gjester");

            ds.ReadXml("gjesteInfo.xml");
            ds.Tables.Add(dt);

            DataColumn dc1 = new DataColumn("Fullt navn");
            DataColumn dc2 = new DataColumn("Start dato");
            DataColumn dc3 = new DataColumn("Antall dager");

            dt.Columns.Add(dc1);
            dt.Columns.Add(dc2);
            dt.Columns.Add(dc3);

            dt.Rows.Add(gjestenavnInput.Text, datoInnsjekk.Text, antallDager.Text);
            ds.Merge(dt);

            ds.WriteXml("gjesteInfo.xml");  
        }

        else
        {

            dt.Rows.Add(gjestenavnInput.Text, datoInnsjekk.Text, antallDager.Text);
            ds.Merge(dt); <- This is where I want to add information to the dataTable, and this is where the error shows up.

            ds.WriteXml("gjesteInfo.xml");
        }



    }
```

Any suggestion to how to avoid the famous "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the else part of your if statement the DataTable is not initialized
But the main problem is, if the file doesn't exist you can't try to read it.....

```
if(!File.Exists("gjesteInfo.xml"))
{
     // The file doesn't exist, create the table to receive initial data here
     dt = new DataTable("Gjester");
     DataColumn dc1 = new DataColumn("Fullt navn");
     DataColumn dc2 = new DataColumn("Start dato");
     DataColumn dc3 = new DataColumn("Antall dager");
     dt.Columns.Add(dc1);
     dt.Columns.Add(dc2);
     dt.Columns.Add(dc3);
     dt.Rows.Add(gjestenavnInput.Text, datoInnsjekk.Text, antallDager.Text);
     ds.Tables.Add(dt);
}
else
{
    // The file exist, read the data and use the first table in the dataset to add new info
    ds.ReadXml("gjesteInfo.xml");
    dt = ds.Tables[0];
    dt.Rows.Add(gjestenavnInput.Text, datoInnsjekk.Text, antallDager.Text);
}
ds.Merge(dt);
ds.WriteXml("gjesteInfo.xml");
```

**EDIT** Seeing your comment below, it seems that your textboxes contain all the previous data entered. If this is the case then the xml file needs to be rewritten from scratch

```
if(File.Exists("gjesteInfo.xml"))
   File.Delete("gjesteInfo.xml")

dt = new DataTable("Gjester");
DataColumn dc1 = new DataColumn("Fullt navn");
DataColumn dc2 = new DataColumn("Start dato");
DataColumn dc3 = new DataColumn("Antall dager");
dt.Columns.Add(dc1);
dt.Columns.Add(dc2);
dt.Columns.Add(dc3);
dt.Rows.Add(gjestenavnInput.Text, datoInnsjekk.Text, antallDager.Text);
ds.Tables.Add(dt);
ds.Merge(dt);
ds.WriteXml("gjesteInfo.xml");
```

Comment: My whole problem is that I only want it to create a new table if the file/table does not allready exist, and if it does exist I want it only to add new information from the textboxes. Not create a new table every time the object is instanced.

Comment: That worked! :) But for some reason, now it stores the old information a another time. I will try to explain : I have three textboxes, when they are all filled and button clicked, the info goes to XML. So if I store : Steve, Male, 23. It goes to the XML. But now if I want to add : Marius, Male, 29. It stores both Steve, Male, 23 and Marius, Male, 29. If I want to add : Super Mario, Male, 45. It stores Steve, Male, 23, Marius, Male , 29 , Super Mario, Male, 45. You understand?

Comment: Yes, this is the expected behavior, it works as a database where you add records

Comment: But not like this? It takes all the previously added info and resubmit it every time a new info is submitted.

Comment: What is your expected behavior then?

Comment: When I register Steve, Male, 23, it will be stored. Then I will add Marius, Male, 29, it will be stored. Then I will ad Super Mario, Male, 45, and it will be stored. In the XML file it will be "Steve, Male, 23. Marius, Male, 29. Mario, Male, 45." and not "Steve, Male, 23.Steve, Male, 23.Marius, Male, 29.Steve, Male, 23.Steve, Male, 23.Marius, Male, 29. Marius, Male, 29. Mario, Male, 45." You see what I mean?

Comment: This means that your input textboxes contains all of the previous entered value? Not just the last one? If so, then we need to recreate the file from scratch every time we press the button

Answer (score 1):

If you run into the `else` part - you've **never** created the `dt` datatable object! You only ever instantiate that inside the `if` block.... you need to have the `dt = new DataTable()` call **before** the `if` statement so that it's valid for both cases....

```
DataTable dt;
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

private void InitDataTable()
{
    dt = new DataTable("Gjester");  <<=== this **BEFORE** the if!

    if (!File.Exists("gjesteInfo.xml"))
    {
       ....... 
    }
    else
    {
       // now, in this case, "dt" has been created, and **NOW** you can operate on it!
       dt.Rows.Add(gjestenavnInput.Text, datoInnsjekk.Text, antallDager.Text);
       ds.Merge(dt); 
       ds.WriteXml("gjesteInfo.xml");
    }
```

Comment: My whole problem is that I only want it to create a new table if the file/table does not allready exist, and if it does exist I want it only to add new information from the textboxes. Not create a new table every time the object is instanced.

Comment: @MariusMathisen: ok, but then you have to somehow use **something existing** in your `else` case - you're not using anything, therefore `dt` is null and trying to add rows to it results in that exception

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
    else
    {
        dt = new DataTable("Gjester");
        dt.Rows.Add(gjestenavnInput.Text, datoInnsjekk.Text, antallDager.Text);
        ds.Merge(dt);
        ds.WriteXml("gjesteInfo.xml");
    }
```